# Collectoiview.Filter does not filter the data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, collectionview

I have a very big problem with my application written in C# WPF MVVM.
When I run my app and write in EmployeeName Textbox for example letter "A" my app dynamic filter of data and then very fast my data is unfiltered.

[image]

But when I comment both ifs in EmployeeName property (This property is top of my code) Filter works fine for other Textboxes. Could you help me? Below I placed my model and xaml.

Employee.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace OneWayTwoWayBinding
{
    public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string employeeName;
        private int? employeeID;
        private int? employeeSalary;
        private string employeeDesigner;
        private string employeeEmailID;
        private Employee selectedEmployee;
        private ICollectionView filteredCollection;
        private string dynamicSearchEmployeeName;
        private int? dynamicSearchEmployeeID;
        private int? dynamicSearchEmployeeSalary;
        private string dynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner;
        private string dynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID;
        private int isSelected;
        private string modeOfExecuting;
        private string rememberValueEmployeeName;
        private int? rememberValueEmployeeID;
        private int? rememberValueEmployeeSalary;
        private string rememberValueEmployeeDesigner;
        private string rememberValueEmployeeEmailID;
        private ObservableCollection<Employee> employees;


        public string EmployeeName
        {
            get
            {
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeName) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeName.Contains(employeeName)); // comment if
                return employeeName;
            }
            set
            {
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeName) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeName.Contains(employeeName)); //[![enter image description here][1]][1]comment if
                employeeName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeName");
            }
        }
        public int? EmployeeID
        {
            get
            {
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => ((employeeID == null) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeID == employeeID);
                return employeeID;
            }
            set
            {

                employeeID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeID");
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => ((employeeID == null) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeID == employeeID);
            }
        }
        public int? EmployeeSalary
        {
            get
            {
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => ((employeeSalary == null) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeSalary == employeeSalary);
                return employeeSalary;
            }
            set
            {
                employeeSalary = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeSalary");
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => ((employeeSalary == null) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeSalary == employeeSalary);
            }
        }
        public string EmployeeDesigner
        {
            get
            {
                //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(employeeDesigner)));
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeDesigner) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeDesigner.Contains(employeeDesigner));
                return employeeDesigner;
            }
            set
            {
                employeeDesigner = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeDesigner");
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeDesigner) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeDesigner.Contains(employeeDesigner));
            }
        }
        public string EmployeeEmailID
        {
            get
            {
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeEmailID) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeEmailID.Contains(employeeEmailID));
                return employeeEmailID;
            }
            set
            {
                employeeEmailID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeEmailID");
                if (FilteredCollection != null)
                    FilteredCollection.Filter = x => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeEmailID) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeEmailID.Contains(employeeEmailID));
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
        {
            get
            {
                return employees;
            }
            set
            {
                employees = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Employees");
            }
        }

        public Employee SelectedEmployee
        {
            get
            {
                if (selectedEmployee == null)
                {
                    ModeOfExecuting = "Searching / Adding Mode";
                }
                //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(selectedEmployee.SelectedEmployee.ToString())));
                return selectedEmployee;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedEmployee = value;

                if (selectedEmployee == null)
                {
                    ModeOfExecuting = "Searching / Adding Mode";
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
                    OnPropertyChanged("ModeOfExecuting");
                }

                if (selectedEmployee != null)
                {
                    if (selectedEmployee.EmployeeName != string.Empty)
                    {
                        RememberValueEmployeeName = selectedEmployee.EmployeeName;
                        DynamicSearchEmployeeName = RememberValueEmployeeName;

                    }
                    if (selectedEmployee.EmployeeID != null)
                    {
                        RememberValueEmployeeID = selectedEmployee.EmployeeID;
                        DynamicSearchEmployeeID = RememberValueEmployeeID;
                    }
                    if (selectedEmployee.EmployeeSalary != null)
                    {
                        RememberValueEmployeeSalary = selectedEmployee.EmployeeSalary;
                        DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary = RememberValueEmployeeSalary;
                    }
                    if (selectedEmployee.EmployeeDesigner != string.Empty)
                    {
                        RememberValueEmployeeDesigner = selectedEmployee.EmployeeDesigner;
                        DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner = RememberValueEmployeeDesigner;
                    }
                    if (selectedEmployee.EmployeeEmailID != string.Empty)
                    {
                        RememberValueEmployeeEmailID = selectedEmployee.EmployeeEmailID;
                        DynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID = RememberValueEmployeeEmailID;
                    }

                    ModeOfExecuting = "Editing Mode";

                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
                    OnPropertyChanged("ModeOfExecuting");
                    OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeName");
                    OnPropertyChanged("DynamicSearchEmployeeName");
                    OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeID");
                    OnPropertyChanged("DynamicSearchEmployeeID");
                    OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeSalary");
                    OnPropertyChanged("DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary");
                    OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeDesigner");
                    OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeDesigner");
                    OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeEmailID");
                    OnPropertyChanged("DynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID");
                }

                //selectedEmployee = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
            }
        }

        public string DynamicSearchEmployeeName
        {
            get
            {
                if (SelectedEmployee == null)
                {
                    //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("null")));
                    EmployeeName = dynamicSearchEmployeeName;
                    //RememberValue = dynamicSearchEmployeeName;
                }
                return dynamicSearchEmployeeName;
            }
            set
            {
                dynamicSearchEmployeeName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DynamicSearchEmployeeName");
            }
        }
        public int? DynamicSearchEmployeeID
        {
            get
            {
                if (SelectedEmployee == null)
                {
                    EmployeeID = dynamicSearchEmployeeID;
                }
                return dynamicSearchEmployeeID;
            }
            set
            {
                dynamicSearchEmployeeID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DynamicSearchEmployeeID");
            }
        }
        public int? DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary
        {
            get
            {
                if (SelectedEmployee == null)
                {
                    EmployeeSalary = dynamicSearchEmployeeSalary;
                }

                return dynamicSearchEmployeeSalary;
            }
            set
            {
                dynamicSearchEmployeeSalary = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary");
            }
        }
        public string DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner
        {
            get
            {
                if (SelectedEmployee == null)
                {
                    EmployeeDesigner = dynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner;
                }
                return dynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner;
            }
            set
            {
                dynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner");
            }
        }
        public string DynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID
        {
            get
            {
                if (SelectedEmployee == null)
                {
                    EmployeeEmailID = dynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID;
                }
                return dynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID;
            }
            set
            {
                dynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID");
            }

        }
        public ICollectionView FilteredCollection
        {
            get
            {
                return filteredCollection;
            }
            set
            {
                filteredCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FilteredCollection");
            }
        }

        public int IsSelected
        {
            get
            {
                //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(changedPathBinding.ToString())));
                return isSelected;
            }
            set
            {
                isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
                //SelectedEmployee.EmployeeName
            }
        }

        public string ModeOfExecuting
        {
            get
            {
                //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(modeOfExecuting.ToString())));
                return modeOfExecuting;
            }
            set
            {
                modeOfExecuting = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ModeOfExecuting");
            }
        }
        public string RememberValueEmployeeName
        {
            get
            {
                //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(changedPathBinding.ToString())));
                return rememberValueEmployeeName;
            }
            set
            {
                rememberValueEmployeeName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeName");
            }
        }
        public int? RememberValueEmployeeID
        {
            get
            {
                //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(changedPathBinding.ToString())));
                return rememberValueEmployeeID;
            }
            set
            {
                rememberValueEmployeeID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeID");
            }
        }
        public int? RememberValueEmployeeSalary
        {
            get
            {
                //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(changedPathBinding.ToString())));
                return rememberValueEmployeeSalary;
            }
            set
            {
                rememberValueEmployeeSalary = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeSalary");
            }
        }
        public string RememberValueEmployeeDesigner
        {
            get
            {
                //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(changedPathBinding.ToString())));
                return rememberValueEmployeeDesigner;
            }
            set
            {
                rememberValueEmployeeDesigner = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeDesigner");
            }
        }
        public string RememberValueEmployeeEmailID
        {
            get
            {
                //Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(changedPathBinding.ToString())));
                return rememberValueEmployeeEmailID;
            }
            set
            {
                rememberValueEmployeeEmailID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RememberValueEmployeeEmailID");
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = null;
        virtual protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindows.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="OneWayTwoWayBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OneWayTwoWayBinding"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ConverterStringFiltering x:Key="ConverterStringFiltering" />
        <local:ConverterButton x:Key="ConverterButton" />
        <local:ConverterIntFiltering x:Key="ConverterIntFiltering" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,20">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView Name="EmployeeListView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="160" Margin="0,259,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="792" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="{Binding IsSelected}" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="EmployeeName" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmployeeName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="EmployeeID" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmployeeID}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="EmployeeSalary" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmployeeSalary}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="EmployeeDesigner" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmployeeDesigner}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="EmployeeEmailID" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmployeeEmailID}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Label Content="Employee Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151" Height="23"/>

        <TextBox Name ="TextboxEmployeeName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="165,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="522" >
            <TextBox.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterStringFiltering}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding Path="SelectedEmployee.EmployeeName" Mode="OneWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                    <Binding Path="DynamicSearchEmployeeName" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>

        <Label Content="EmployeeID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Height="23"/>

        <TextBox Name ="TextboxEmployeeID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="165,91,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="522" >
            <TextBox.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterIntFiltering}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">

                    <Binding Path="SelectedEmployee.EmployeeID" Mode="OneWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                    <Binding Path="DynamicSearchEmployeeID"  Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>


        <Label Content="EmpoyeeSalary" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151" Height="23"/>

        <TextBox Name="TextboxEmployeeSalary" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="165,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="522" >
            <TextBox.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterIntFiltering}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">

                    <Binding Path="SelectedEmployee.EmployeeSalary" Mode="OneWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                    <Binding Path="DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary"  Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>

        <Label Content="EmployeeDesigner" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151" Height="23"/>

        <TextBox Name ="TextboxEmployeeDesigner" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="165,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="522" >
            <TextBox.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterStringFiltering}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding Path="SelectedEmployee.EmployeeDesigner" Mode="OneWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                    <Binding Path="DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner"  Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>

        <Label Content="EmployeeEmailID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,221,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151" Height="23"/>
        <TextBox Name="TextboxEmployeeEmailID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="165,221,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="522" >

            <TextBox.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterStringFiltering}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding Path="SelectedEmployee.EmployeeEmailID" Mode="OneWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                    <Binding Path="DynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID"  Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>

        <Button Content="Update" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="692,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.017,0.456" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" >
            <Button.CommandParameter>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterButton}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeName" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeID" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeSalary" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeDesigner" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeEmailID" Path="Text"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.CommandParameter>
        </Button>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ModeOfExecuting, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="390" Height="37" FontSize="20"/>
        <Button Content="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="692,116,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.017,0.456" Command="{Binding ClearCommand}" >
            <Button.CommandParameter>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterButton}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeName" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeID" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeSalary" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeDesigner" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeEmailID" Path="Text"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.CommandParameter>
        </Button>
        <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="692,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.017,0.456" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" >
            <Button.CommandParameter>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterButton}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeName" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeID" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeSalary" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeDesigner" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="TextboxEmployeeEmailID" Path="Text"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.CommandParameter>
        </Button>
        <Button Content="Remove" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="692,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.017,0.456" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It looks like you're filtering on the old value of 'employeeName', then changing it to the new value. Have you tried assigning the new value first?

Comment: But when I comment both ifs in EmployeeName property filtering works fine for other properties. How is it possible? Code is the same for other properties.

Comment: That is not the problem. It works regardless of the order because filter is a lambda that is executed at a later point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are overriding the filter in each one of your getters. 
The framework may be calling these getters soon after you change the employee name, thus applying filters of other fields and overriding the name filter

Remove the filter assignments from the getters, but keep them in the setters

Comment: When I remove from getters it works fine. But I do not understand why it does not work only for this one property? Why those ifs should be removed but rest from another properties not?

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, because your code is quite complex, but it probably means that the getters of one (or more) of the other properties are being called after you change the employee name. You can find out which property getter is being called by placing breakpoints everywhere you set the .Filter - but make sure to remove the filter override from ALL getters. It makes no sense to filter by a field just because the value is being read.

Comment: Tomorrow I will put github link of my code☺  I hope you will be able to answer my question. BTW I was a software tester and I start learning programming☺

Comment: Sure thing. If my answer solves your problem, though, please mark it as the accepted answer with the green tick :)

Comment: Hello. I delete my folders with properties and rewrite all manually. Prolems stop existing. Magic :)